# Electron - In-App Purchase - how to validate apple receipt using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, in-app-purchase, electron, receipt-validation

I have an Electron app with [In-App Purchases](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/in-app-purchases) integrated.

The In-App Purchases themselves are working - I can pull down the price and display it - and the user can buy the IAP. However, I'm having trouble validating the Apple receipt.

I'm using this [apple-store-receipt-validator-in-php](https://github.com/aminmahdi/apple-store-receipt-validator-in-php/blob/master/iTunesVerify.php) PHP script to validate the Apple receipt. And this works fine if I use the default encoded receipt data ("ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQX..." - line 18 on the PHP script) where I get this response:

```
{  
    "receipt":{  
        "original_purchase_date_pst":"2012-04-30 08:05:55 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "original_transaction_id":"1000000046178817",
        "original_purchase_date_ms":"1335798355868",
        "transaction_id":"1000000046178817",
        "quantity":"1",
        "product_id":"com.mindmobapp.download",
        "bvrs":"20120427",
        "purchase_date_ms":"1335798355868",
        "purchase_date":"2012-04-30 15:05:55 Etc\/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date":"2012-04-30 15:05:55 Etc\/GMT",
        "purchase_date_pst":"2012-04-30 08:05:55 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "bid":"com.mindmobapp.MindMob",
        "item_id":"521129812"
    },
    "status":0
}
```

However, when I read the Apple receipt file, base64 encode it and post it to the validator script within Electron, I get the following response:

```
{
    status:21002
}
```

According to the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW5), this error code means:

```
The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing.
```

Here is how I'm reading the Apple receipt, base64 encoding it and sending it to the php script:

```
inAppPurchase.on('transactions-updated', (event, transactions) => {
    transactions.forEach(function (transaction) {
        var payment = transaction.payment

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case 'purchased':
                // Get the receipt url.
                let receiptURL = inAppPurchase.getReceiptURL()

                // get receipt data from file
                var receiptRaw = fs.readFileSync(receiptURL)

                // base64 encode the receipt data
                var receiptEncoded = receiptRaw.toString('base64')

                // submit the receipt file to the server and check if it is valid
                $this.$axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    data: {
                        res: receiptEncoded
                    },
                    url: 'http://temp.dconnell.co.uk'
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log('response: ', response);
                    if (!response.data.status) {
                        console.log('Valid receipt.');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Invalid receipt!');
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

                // Finish the transaction.
                inAppPurchase.finishTransactionByDate(transaction.transactionDate)
                break

            default:
                break
        }

    })
})
```

I've also tried using the [js-base64](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64) library to encode the Apple receipt data instead, to no avail:

```
var receiptEncoded = Base64.encode(receiptRaw)
```

### Edit 1

Here is the server side code I'm using:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{ 
    $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
}
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

#######################################################################
#######################################################################
##                                                                   ##
##                                                                   ##
##  PROGRAMMED BY AMIN MAHDI MAMDOOH (ARS NETWORK DEVELOPER TEAMS),  ##
##  ARS Network (M) Sdn. Bhd. , http://www.ars-network.com           ##
##  http://www.ARSgroupco.com , http://www.mamdooh.me                ##
##                                                                   ##
##  Copyright (c) 2000-2015 ARSgroupco.com                           ##
##  Created @ 2015.01.28                                             ##
##  iOS Web Application Control Panel VERSION 2.00                   ##
##                                                                   ##
##                                                                   ##
#######################################################################
#######################################################################

// $res = "ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXBNVUJDODZBbHpOaWtWNVl0clpBTWlKUWJLOEVk
// ZVhrNjNrV0JBWHpsQzhkWEd1anE0N1puSVlLb0ZFMW9OL0ZTOGNYbEZmcDlZWHQ5
// aU1CZEwyNTBsUlJtaU5HYnloaXRyeVlWQVFvcmkzMlc5YVIwVDhML2FZVkJkZlcr
// T3kvUXlQWkVtb05LeGhudDJXTlNVRG9VaFo4Wis0cFA3MHBlNWtVUWxiZElWaEFB
// QURWekNDQTFNd2dnSTdvQU1DQVFJQ0NHVVVrVTNaV0FTMU1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RR
// RUJCUVVBTUg4eEN6QUpCZ05WQkFZVEFsVlRNUk13RVFZRFZRUUtEQXBCY0hCc1pT
// QkpibU11TVNZd0pBWURWUVFMREIxQmNIQnNaU0JEWlhKMGFXWnBZMkYwYVc5dUlF
// RjFkR2h2Y21sMGVURXpNREVHQTFVRUF3d3FRWEJ3YkdVZ2FWUjFibVZ6SUZOMGIz
// SmxJRU5sY25ScFptbGpZWFJwYjI0Z1FYVjBhRzl5YVhSNU1CNFhEVEE1TURZeE5U
// SXlNRFUxTmxvWERURTBNRFl4TkRJeU1EVTFObG93WkRFak1DRUdBMVVFQXd3YVVI
// VnlZMmhoYzJWU1pXTmxhWEIwUTJWeWRHbG1hV05oZEdVeEd6QVpCZ05WQkFzTUVr
// RndjR3hsSUdsVWRXNWxjeUJUZEc5eVpURVRNQkVHQTFVRUNnd0tRWEJ3YkdVZ1NX
// NWpMakVMTUFrR0ExVUVCaE1DVlZNd2daOHdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVCQlFBRGdZ
// MEFNSUdKQW9HQkFNclJqRjJjdDRJclNkaVRDaGFJMGc4cHd2L2NtSHM4cC9Sd1Yv
// cnQvOTFYS1ZoTmw0WElCaW1LalFRTmZnSHNEczZ5anUrK0RyS0pFN3VLc3BoTWRk
// S1lmRkU1ckdYc0FkQkVqQndSSXhleFRldngzSExFRkdBdDFtb0t4NTA5ZGh4dGlJ
// ZERnSnYyWWFWczQ5QjB1SnZOZHk2U01xTk5MSHNETHpEUzlvWkhBZ01CQUFHamNq
// QndNQXdHQTFVZEV3RUIvd1FDTUFBd0h3WURWUjBqQkJnd0ZvQVVOaDNvNHAyQzBn
// RVl0VEpyRHRkREM1RllRem93RGdZRFZSMFBBUUgvQkFRREFnZUFNQjBHQTFVZERn
// UVdCQlNwZzRQeUdVakZQaEpYQ0JUTXphTittVjhrOVRBUUJnb3Foa2lHOTJOa0Jn
// VUJCQUlGQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRVUZBQU9DQVFFQUVhU2JQanRtTjRDL0lC
// M1FFcEszMlJ4YWNDRFhkVlhBZVZSZVM1RmFaeGMrdDg4cFFQOTNCaUF4dmRXLzNl
// VFNNR1k1RmJlQVlMM2V0cVA1Z204d3JGb2pYMGlreVZSU3RRKy9BUTBLRWp0cUIw
// N2tMczlRVWU4Y3pSOFVHZmRNMUV1bVYvVWd2RGQ0TndOWXhMUU1nNFdUUWZna1FR
// Vnk4R1had1ZIZ2JFL1VDNlk3MDUzcEdYQms1MU5QTTN3b3hoZDNnU1JMdlhqK2xv
// SHNTdGNURXFlOXBCRHBtRzUrc2s0dHcrR0szR01lRU41LytlMVFUOW5wL0tsMW5q
// K2FCdzdDMHhzeTBiRm5hQWQxY1NTNnhkb3J5L0NVdk02Z3RLc21uT09kcVRlc2Jw
// MGJzOHNuNldxczBDOWRnY3hSSHVPTVoydG04bnBMVW03YXJnT1N6UT09IjsKCSJw
// dXJjaGFzZS1pbmZvIiA9ICJld29KSW05eWFXZHBibUZzTFhCMWNtTm9ZWE5sTFdS
// aGRHVXRjSE4wSWlBOUlDSXlNREV5TFRBMExUTXdJREE0T2pBMU9qVTFJRUZ0WlhK
// cFkyRXZURzl6WDBGdVoyVnNaWE1pT3dvSkltOXlhV2RwYm1Gc0xYUnlZVzV6WVdO
// MGFXOXVMV2xrSWlBOUlDSXhNREF3TURBd01EUTJNVGM0T0RFM0lqc0tDU0ppZG5K
// eklpQTlJQ0l5TURFeU1EUXlOeUk3Q2draWRISmhibk5oWTNScGIyNHRhV1FpSUQw
// Z0lqRXdNREF3TURBd05EWXhOemc0TVRjaU93b0pJbkYxWVc1MGFYUjVJaUE5SUNJ
// eElqc0tDU0p2Y21sbmFXNWhiQzF3ZFhKamFHRnpaUzFrWVhSbExXMXpJaUE5SUNJ
// eE16TTFOems0TXpVMU9EWTRJanNLQ1NKd2NtOWtkV04wTFdsa0lpQTlJQ0pqYjIw
// dWJXbHVaRzF2WW1Gd2NDNWtiM2R1Ykc5aFpDSTdDZ2tpYVhSbGJTMXBaQ0lnUFNB
// aU5USXhNVEk1T0RFeUlqc0tDU0ppYVdRaUlEMGdJbU52YlM1dGFXNWtiVzlpWVhC
// d0xrMXBibVJOYjJJaU93b0pJbkIxY21Ob1lYTmxMV1JoZEdVdGJYTWlJRDBnSWpF
// ek16VTNPVGd6TlRVNE5qZ2lPd29KSW5CMWNtTm9ZWE5sTFdSaGRHVWlJRDBnSWpJ
// d01USXRNRFF0TXpBZ01UVTZNRFU2TlRVZ1JYUmpMMGROVkNJN0Nna2ljSFZ5WTJo
// aGMyVXRaR0YwWlMxd2MzUWlJRDBnSWpJd01USXRNRFF0TXpBZ01EZzZNRFU2TlRV
// Z1FXMWxjbWxqWVM5TWIzTmZRVzVuWld4bGN5STdDZ2tpYjNKcFoybHVZV3d0Y0hW
// eVkyaGhjMlV0WkdGMFpTSWdQU0FpTWpBeE1pMHdOQzB6TUNBeE5Ub3dOVG8xTlNC
// RmRHTXZSMDFVSWpzS2ZRPT0iOwoJImVudmlyb25tZW50IiA9ICJTYW5kYm94IjsK
// CSJwb2QiID0gIjEwMCI7Cgkic2lnbmluZy1zdGF0dXMiID0gIjAiOwp9";

if (isset($_GET['res'])) {
    $res = $_GET['res'];
}

// iTunes Validator V2 Start Function
function receipt_Result_ITC($isSandbox,$receipt_data) {

    if ($isSandbox) {
        $url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/";
    }
    else {
        $url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $data_string = json_encode(array(
        'receipt-data' => $receipt_data
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $output   = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (200 != $httpCode) {
        echo "Error validating App Store transaction receipt. Response HTTP code $httpCode";
        }
    $decoded = json_decode($output, TRUE);
    return $decoded;
}
// iTunes Validator V2 End Function

$result = receipt_Result_ITC (true,$res);
$jsonResult = json_encode($result);

echo $jsonResult;
?>
```

I believe I'm not reading and / or encoding the Apple receipt file data correctly before sending. How can I do this correctly?

### Edit 2

This is the result of `var receiptEncoded = receiptRaw.toString('base64')`:

```
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
```

Or if I use `var receiptEncoded = Base64.encode(receiptRaw)` then this is the result:

```
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
```

Also, here is the result of `let receiptURL = inAppPurchase.getReceiptURL()`:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/email-snippets/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt
```

Comment: Can you share the server-side code of your http://temp.dconnell.co.uk endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added this above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server-side works and `receiptRaw.toString('base64')` is correct.

If I send the following to https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/ I get `"status": 0` (so it works).

```
{
    "receipt-data": "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"
}
```

---

However, your server decodes the parameter when you call `$_GET['res']`.

> The GET variables are passed through urldecode(). (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

**So what you send to the Apple's verification endpoint is not a base64 encoded receipt.**

Moreover, you use `$_GET['res']` while you call your server with a POST.

I suggest you to use `$res = $_POST['res']` or `Content-Type: application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (see https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2018/06/read-json-request-data-with-php/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added these to the question. There is no protocol in `receiptURL`. It just returns the file path (see question above).

Comment: Thanks so much. I've got it working now! I had previously tried using `$_POST['res']` instead of `$_GET['res']` but `$_POST` was appearing empty. However, there was one more fly in the ointment. I had to stringify the data before sending it in the axios post request. I.E. `$this.$axios({ data: qs.stringify({ res: receiptEncoded }), ... )`. Also had to pull in the qs package beforehand with `const qs = require('qs')`. Thank you!!!